# Could anyone please help me find the error in the code

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, mathematica-online

I have a problem with `DSolve` and the following code:

```
DSolve[{D[Ψ[x], x, x] == κ^2 Ψ[x],
  Ψ[0] == Ψs, Ψ[Infinity] == 0}, Ψ, x]
```

The error getting displayed in Mathematica is:

```
DSolve::bvlim: For some branches of the general solution, unable to 
compute the limit at the given points. Some of the solutions may be lost.
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ode=w''[x]==k^2*w[x]
Ic={w[0]==ws,w[L]==0}
sol=DSolveValue[{ode,Ic},w[x],x]
Assuming[k>0,Simplify[Limit[sol,L->Infinity]]]
```

Gives

```
Exp[-kx] ws
```